# How tall is Supreme Leader Snoke?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, snoke

In *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*, we see Supreme Leader Snoke a few times dispensing orders to his subordinates.

> However, we always see him communicating via hologram, and we've seen in previous *Star Wars* films that these holograms are often projected at a different size than the original person is.

So how tall is he really?  I don't think we ever got a good shot of him with something to give a sense of scale.

Comment: *If* he is a Muun, as some fan theories hold, then according to Wookieepedia he should be about 1.9 meters tall. This isn't such an extraordinary height, so *if* he was a Muun, he'd just be projecting a big image for the sake of looking intimidating?

Comment: Yeah I always figured it was just the hologram

Comment: Does canon confirmation of his tallness as a fact suffuce, or are you looking for actual measurment?

Comment: @DVK Looking for anything, but saying Snoke's hologram is tall is just repeating the question back to me.

Comment: @Keen - canon info says he is tall even absent hologram. See my edit please

Comment: I like the hint on the following Tweet: https://twitter.com/fracassifa/status/718146510349799424

Comment: I imagine Snope is looking at a tiny hologram of Ren on the other end for the eye-lines to work.

Comment: Considering that so called "Snoke" is just Gollum after he escaped with The One Ring (which explains his rise to power), I'd say he is about 3 feet tall.

Comment: However tall he was, he now is half as tall.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to the *Alan Dean Forser's TFA novelization* (Chapter X), he was tall.

> Seated on the raised platform that was the focus of the chamber was the blue-tinted holo of Supreme Leader Snoke. **Tall and gaunt**, he was humanoid but not human.
>   Seated in shadow, the tall, slender form **loomed over the other two men**.

Lest this be taken as "Hologram effect only", WoG is that he is tall as well:

> But Neal Scanlan, chief of creature and droid effects, told PEOPLE, “This character is much better executed as a CGI character. That’s just a practical reality **when he’s 7-foot-something tall; he’s very, very thin**.” ([source](http://makingstarwars.net/2015/12/people-magazine-confirms-snokes-height-and-weight-from-star-wars-the-force-awakens/))

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this tells us anything. "Tall" could really mean anything, and since he's on a raised platform he doesn't even need to be taller than the average to loom over them.

Comment: I wonder though how it came that the empire lets a non human in a ledership position oO

Comment: @Thomas - Admiral Thrawn. Darth Plagueis. Several other non-humans in Palpanine's inner circle.

Comment: Whoever downvoted (and @AnthonyGrist) - please see the edit.

Comment: @dvk Good point about Plagueis although he wasnt part of the empire. Thrawn though isnt canon any longer yny more sadly. (btw wasnt a downvoter)

Comment: I didn't downvote, and have now upvoted on the basis of the second quote. He still looked bigger than "7-foot-something" on the hologram to me, so it's possible there's still some distortion going on, but seems he's also naturally tall.

Comment: @Thomas (spoiler) *Aftermath* Disney canon novel has a weird senior admiral that basically **screams** "Thrawn" in the end.

Comment: @dvk I know the novel but I always thought THAT one was a human

Comment: Care to update after *The Last Jedi?*

Comment: @Paul - no not particularly :)

Answer (score -2):

[This Wookieepedia article](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Snoke) contains a lot of canon insight as to who Snoke might be.

He is ca 7 feet tall but not a Muun or Plagueis, clearly, as he has a humanoid nose, no elongated skull, black alien eyes which is inconsistent with those of a Sith Lord, etc etc.

I reckon Snoke could be a powerful balanced force user, perhaps the most powerful, previously controlling (and now representing) groups like the Jal Shey or similar in the EU.