# Who's that big scary guy talking to Kylo Ren and Hux?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, character-identification

In *The Force Awakens*, Kylo Ren and General Hux go talk to someone who is shown as the hologram of a big, weird, and scary guy. They call him “Supreme Leader,” and he seems to be the power behind the ruler.

Who is he? Where does he come from? How was he tied into all of this?

Comment: At this point, apart from some biographical information, we just don't know. This will all presumably be answered in the upcoming 2 sequels. I'm *tempted* to close this as per our "future works" policy...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Supreme Leader Snoke

Snoke follows the Dark Side of the Force. He is Kylo Ren's master.

> He persuaded Ben Solo to turn to the Dark Side. Ben Solo then took on the name Kylo Ren.

His [Wookieepedia page](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Snoke) says:

> Snoke was a male individual who served as the Supreme Leader of the First Order approximately thirty years after the Battle of Endor.

Kylo Ren and General Hux answer to him.

> Snoke was a powerful figure, skilled with the dark side of the Force, who had trained at least one Force-sensitive, Kylo Ren, as an apprentice.

Currently, there's not a whole lot we know about him. His backstory will likely be expanded in the upcoming films.

---

As to why he appears so large, he is actually communicating to them via hologram. Since the projected holograms come in different sizes, it's hard to tell his actual size. It can be assumed he would probably be "normal sized". For more on his height, see [How tall is Supreme Leader Snoke?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111164/how-tall-is-supreme-leader-snoke)

[image]

> Snoke's design is similar to Star Wars concept artist Ralph McQuarrie’s early design for Emperor Palpatine.

[image]

Comment: How did he get so big?

Comment: @bleh He ate all his veggies when he was little, like a good boy. ;)

Comment: Ugh. I was gonna answer with the novelization + film screenshots. But don't wanna steal your thunder :)

Comment: @DVK that's the nicest thing I've seen you do! lol. But feel free to answer if you want. Or you can add to my answer (mwahaha) :)

Comment: @RedCaio - ordinarily I actually would but significantly improving others' answers is within the limits of my strike

Comment: "significantly improving others' answers is within the limits of my strike" wait, what? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @RedCaio Due to complications with certain aspects of the site and the people who run it DVK is on "strike" which means he won't do any of the admin work for the site or effectively that. Things like editing, reviewing, closing questions, general moderator esc actions.

Comment: @CandiedMango not that I pretend to know what any of that means, but I thought Richard was the one "on strike" whatever that means. His avatar is an "on strike" sign.

Comment: Oh no.  I just realized that Snoke has almost the exact same facial scar as Kylo Ren received in his battle with Rey.  I really hope JJ Abrams isn't thinking of bringing time travel to the SW universe and having Kylo Ren train himself.

Answer (score 0):

That is Snoke. He is the new grandmaster: Kylo Ren’s mentor and Supreme Leader ("emperor") of the First Order.

There are very few theories about Snoke’s past.

He might be Darth Plagueis, Palpatine’s master, and have survived from his overthrow by Palpatine, since Plagueis could change the midi-chlorians into forms of life.

Snoke could also be Palpatine. Somehow Palpatine could have survived when he was picked up and thrown by Vader into the shaft.
(That could be why Snoke is deformed and scarred.)
He comes back and changes his identity. He appears big in holograms just like he does for Vader. (*Empire Strikes Back*)

Comment: There are no Sith in *TFA*, and is clearly not Palpatine or intended to be. Production people have said he's an entirely new character, which probably rules out Plagueis as well.

Comment: Production people have been known to be not 100% truthful in the past. "It's not Kahn"