# Who is Snoke and how did he come to power?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, snoke

With the release of The Last Jedi and related material, do we find out the origins and Snoke's rise to power? How did another such powerful Sith lord hide from Palpatine and quickly after his demise, took his place?
The Force Awakens introduces him to the cannon, but leaves his character a mystery to the viewer and now with the new movie, we don't really learn anything new about him ([apart from his actual height](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111164/how-tall-is-supreme-leader-snoke)) and

> he's gone before we get a chance to learn more.

Is there any canon material released around the release of The Last Jedi that tells his story?

Comment: Snoke is a clone of Palpatine. After remnants of Galactic Empire started to crumple post-RotJ, it was decided by warlords to clone Palpatine using DNA salvaged from his body. But, the DNA wasn't in perfect health, so Snoke was born with defects. But, his mind and midi-chlorians concentration turned out to be more than average.

Comment: @Bat that's very interesting, but do you have any source on that? Perhaps you can improve that into a full answer

Comment: Why can't he be just some random dude with Force powers? I mean, the galaxy is _really_ big, and Force sensitivity is not all that rare. Rise and fall of the Empire has sent the galaxy into turmoil, creating fertile soil for people like that climbing to power. In universe, no one knows who he is - and so neither do we.

Comment: [Snoke is probably not a Sith](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/124997/31936), and @Bat is making stuff up.

Comment: How is this question different than https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/176356/31936?

Comment: Snoke survived a long and epic journey to Mustafar to return the Force Ring to [the Dagobah system](https://img.memecdn.com/use-the-force--gandalf_o_2334065.jpg). Afterwards, he returned as the King.

Comment: @Null I thought about voting to close as a dupe, but the other question is limited to just things learned about Snoke in TLJ, while this is just generally asking who he is. Take the TLJ part out and it looks a lot less like a dupe.

Comment: How is this question, about The Last Jedi, a duplicate of a question from 2015?

Comment: This is not asking for an identity connection re: Snoke & Darth Plagueis. That question is complete speculation and does not address “how he came to power.” Please unlink these questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Who is Snoke**?

According to [the Starwars wiki](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Snoke)

> Snoke was a Force-sensitive humanoid alien who served as the Supreme Leader of the First Order approximately thirty years after the Battle of Endor. He had a distinctive, idiosyncratic bone and facial structure. Snoke was a powerful figure, skilled with the dark side of the Force, who had trained the Force-sensitive Kylo Ren and at least one other apprentice.

[**Where is he from?**](http://metro.co.uk/2017/12/14/supreme-leader-snoke-come-appear-force-awakens-7158544/)

> Where he came from has been a mystery to Star Wars fans, with much speculation over his origins.

**How did he come to power?**

His rise to power is pretty much unknown and we don't really need to know as the [CB: Star Wars](http://comicbook.com/starwars/2017/12/15/star-wars-the-last-jedi-supreme-leader-snoke-identity/) puts it:

> Many theories have swirled around the internet about who Snoke's true identity is and he how became powerful, ranging from the Emperor himself to Mace Windu to the very first Jedi. Potentially, all of these theories are just as valid as any other, but given the sudden decimation of the Supreme Leader, his true identity is ultimately irrelevant to his story, as he most likely won't be featured in future films.

Comment: Solid answer, but I'd probably spoiler the last quote. It also doesn't feel like the first quote needs to be spoilered, but I guess it's better to be safe than spoil someone.

Answer (score 1):

Real truth about Snoke is that **Disney doesn't know what to do with him**. Most important informations about Snoke are:

1. He is powerful Dark Side Force user.
2. He has watched Empire rise and fall, i.e. he has lived in Empire's era.
3. He is **not** a Sith.

Point no.3 is what creates trouble for Disney. Either they abandon continuity (Anakin destroyed Sith for all times) or they have big problem explaining how did Snoke become so powerful, who trained him, what did he and his teacher do all this time etc ... In order not to bother with this (at least for now), Disney decided to kill him off (at least temporarily) thus "solving" problem by sweeping it under the rug.